# Scala remove a single object from a list

Tags: scala

I am translating some java code into scala and I am having trouble removing an object from a list I'm using.  My code is below

```
def removeCar (usedCarList: List[UsedCars]):List[UsedCars] ={
    //var vinNumber = "";
    var car = new UsedCars();
    println("Please enter the Vin Number");
    var vinNumber = readLine();
    var i = 0;
    var found = false;
    while (i < usedCarList.length){
        car = usedCarList(i);
        if (vinNumber == car.vinNumber) {
            usedCarList.drop(i);
            println("** Removed Car with Vin Number " + vinNumber + " **");
            println(car.vinNumber);
            found = true;
        }
```

I know drop is not what I'm looking to use but I can't figure out how to drop an element at a given index.

Comment: You can't do this with immutable List: you have to use classes from `scala.collection.mutable` package.

Comment: You may have mistakenly assumed scala `List` to be similiar to `java.util.List`. Unfortunately, they are completely different things.

Comment: You're free to make a new immutable list each time you want to break it.  You can do it on index with a List.splitAt() and then removing off the head or the tail of the split.  I'd try List.dropWhile() instead your current loop.  If you need a side effect like printing from the predicate, you could def it.

Comment: I had a chance to try List.dropWhile() last night for this case and it didn't work, but List.filterNot() from @0__'s answer works well to generate the new list ( still learning Scala... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, Scala's `List` has a very different approach. You can still use that type as it's quite simple and useful, only you cannot use something like `drop`. In any case, your type of iteration with **variables** `car` and `found`, **`while`** and `if` etc., is still very java'ish.

Try to use the mapping, splitting and filtering functions that Scala collections provide.

```
def removeCar (usedCarsList: List[UsedCars]): List[UsedCars] ={
  println("Please enter the Vin Number")
  val vinNumber = readLine()
  val (same, different) = usedCarsList.partition(_ == vinNumber)
  if (same.nonEmpty) {
    println("** Removed Car with Vin Number " + vinNumber + " **")
    same.map(_.vinNumber).foreach(println)
  }
  different
}
```

If you don't care about verifying that the list changed, you can also just do a

```
val removed = usedCarsList.filterNot(_ == vinNumber)
```

The method I used above, `partition`, is [right at the start of the Scala collections introduction.](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html).